# Why does the Intel compiler miss header file changes in Xcode 5?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, dependencies, xcode5

I am using the combination of the `C++ Compiler XE 14.0 Update 1` and `Xcode 5.0.2` running on `OS X 10.9.1` and am seeing compilation issues (which is reproducible among 2 of my other colleagues on similar setups).

The problem is the following: **any changes** to header files within a project are not treated according to expected dependencies and recompilation of respective compilation units and relinking of products is **not** carried out.

It has to be said that using Apple's LLVM compiler does **not** exhibit this behaviour.

Workarounds to getting things built right (all impractical) are:

- clean the project and rebuild everything
- ​close the Xcode project and re-open it and build
- relaunch Xcode and build

A very simple Xcode project can be created that demonstrates the issue.

1. Create a new Xcode, blank.
2. Create a C++ library target - dynamic.
3. Add two files, e.g. a `foo.cpp` and a `foo.h` file
4. Set the compiler to Intel's C++ XE 14
5. Build - all is well
6. Build again - no extra work, all is well
7. Modify the foo.h file
8. Build - fails to rebuild correctly.

A link to a sample Xcode project can be found here:

https://github.com/surething/DependencyTest

Once built, any changes to the `*.h` file does not incur a recompilation and a relink of the generated `*.dylib`.

Comment: Intel has responded that this is not an issue with the Intel compiler, and is instead an issue with Xcode. It was [mentioned](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/498771) that it would be fixed in an upcoming release of Xcode.